# number format in pgfplots axis

Tags: pgfplots, formatting, punctuation

How can I change the type of the decimal/thousand separator from the american one to the european one? More precisely, I want:

- "1000" to be written as is, instead of "1,000"
- "0,1" instead of "0.1"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The number formatting is changed using the `/pgf/number format` keys, which are described starting on page 546 of the [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). In your case, you would want to set `/pgf/number format/use comma` to set the comma as the decimal separator, and `/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}` to suppress separators for the groups of thousands.

When setting several subkeys, you can save yourself a bit of typing by first changing to the main key using `/pgf/number format/.cd`, and then setting the number formats.

Since I assume you want the number format to be consistent all through your plot, you should set the options for the whole axis.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={}]
\addplot +[domain=0:1] {(x+rnd)*4000};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to have pgfplots(and TikZ) to format numbers like \num{} from the siunitx package (ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/siunitx.html). -Like my numbers in the rest of the document.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Yes, you can set `xticklabel=\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=1]{\tick}` (or similar).

Comment: I think a new option like `american number format` or `european number format` could be useful here (this is a comment for @ChristianFeuersänger). Otherwise, if one uses `siunitx`, the number format should be gathered from the options set in that package.

Comment: For version 3.0.1a, the description of the `pgf/number format` keys start page 945.

Answer (score 16):

**Edit:** As per Jake's comments: using `set decimal separator={,}` instead of `use comma` introduces an unwanted thin space after the comma. Interestingly, if you use `set decimal separator={.}`, this doesn't happen.  So, better to use `use comma` instead as per Jake's solution.

---

Use `set thousands separator={}` and `set decimal separator={,}` which yields:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={},
          fixed},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled x ticks = false,
          set decimal separator={,},
          fixed}%
     ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (0.1,1000)
  (0.2,1100)
  (0.3,1200)
  };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `set decimal separator={{,}}` to avoid this behavior.

Comment: @PatrickBergner I have tried this and it is not improving the situation. Any idea?

Comment: @Magpie: Without more details it is difficult to help. I'd suggest posting a new question. You should refer to this question and show _exactly_ how this did not improve the situation.

Comment: @PeterGrill it's ok I fixed it. See answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait.I just noticed that the OP actually wanted this formatting I can't get my head around that but I will delete anyway.

Comment: @Magpie: In some countries (like Germany) a comma is used as the decimal separator and a period as the thousands separator. It's just a convention.

Comment: I thought the language of mathematics was universal. What fresh hell is this?

Comment: @Magpie is called i18n. Number notation is more a language (local) matter than mathematics. Traditional Spanish, for example, is using a raised comma for decimal separation, and a dot for thousand separator. Italy has a similar convention, just with standard comma. Could be hell, but it is in the same category of hell as "why don't anyone speak English?" ;-)