# Configuring Decimal Separator in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [number format in pgfplots axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31276/number-format-in-pgfplots-axis)

I'm using `pgfplots` package to create graphs. I would set up the decimal pointer. As default comma `,` is set up. I would have the point `.`

Which is the command?

Comment: By default, the decimal separator should be `.`, and `,` should be the thousands separator (so you'd see numbers like `10,000.99`. For changing this, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31276/2552

Comment: Not sure about your question but, perhaps you are using `babel` package, and it is changing your `.` for `,` following the standard of your language?