# Removing commas in x-axis values for pgfplots graph

Tags: pgfplots

I want to remove the commas in the x-axis values for a pgfplots graph. Here is an example with commas:

[image]

Is there a way of removing these commas only in the x-values (not in the y-values)?

Comment: In particular, the `x tick label style` bits from this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31277/32374

Comment: @darthbith Using that part of that answer does not change anything.

Comment: @darthbith Using the accepted answer of the one you linked to does work. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to copy the bits from the `y tick label style` in that answer into an `x tick label style` in your document

Comment: In the accepted answer, you're setting the tick label style for all the ticks, so be careful if you get thousands that you want the comma for in the y-axis! :-)

Comment: Go ahead and create an answer consisting of your first comment and I'll accept it.