# Box plot with pgfplots package

Tags: pgfplots, context

I did my first box with pgfplots package. I have several questions :

How to write numbers without commas with a thousands separator ?

How to have a larger distance between the box and the x axis ?

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]
\usepgfplotslibrary[statistics]
\pgfplotsset[width=12cm,compat=1.11]

\starttext

\starttikzpicture
\startaxis[y=1.5cm,
       axis y line=none,
       axis x line=bottom,
       enlarge x limits,
       thick
      ]

\addplot+[
          green,line width=0.5mm,
          boxplot prepared={
          median=1500,
          upper quartile=2500,
          lower quartile=1200,
          upper whisker=3000,
          lower whisker=1000
           },
          ] coordinates {};

\stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first question can be answered by a number of posts on this site, e.g., [number format in pgfplots axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31276/32374). The simple solution is to add code for number formatting to your axis labels:

```
/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
```

Your second question can be resolved by setting `ymin=0` (or really, any `ymin` value, `0` happens to be a good choice IMHO).

<del>I would note that the `\pgfplotsset` line was giving errors for me, but I have no experience with `context` so I can't be sure what was causing the error.</del>

The error on that line was due to using square braces instead of curly braces around the options. If I correct the error, the default ticks are overlapping, so in the code below is a specification of a reasonable number of ticks. You should change this as you see fit.

Finally, I prefer to end each line of the options (even the last one) with a comma. This makes adding new lines to the options easier - I don't have to remember to add a comma, and my version control only tells me that one line has changed, instead of two. So you'll see that here, but its purely personal preference :-)

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]
\usepgfplotslibrary[statistics]
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm, compat=1.11}

\starttext

\starttikzpicture
\startaxis[y=1.5cm,
       axis y line=none,
       axis x line=bottom,
       enlarge x limits,
       thick,
       x tick label style={
           /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
       },
       xtick={800,1200,...,3200},
       ymin=0,
      ]

\addplot+[
          green,line width=0.5mm,
          boxplot prepared={
          median=1500,
          upper quartile=2500,
          lower quartile=1200,
          upper whisker=3000,
          lower whisker=1000,
           },
          ] coordinates {};

\stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @ darthbith Sorry for the late reply, much work !
Thank you, it is very clear, but my learning of TikZ will be longer than Metapost or PSTricks.

Comment: @Fabrice You're welcome, no problem. TikZ is a very large package, for sure :-)