# tikz: Node values with comma

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz diagram with some numbers in it. But I want, taht tikz displayes "0.38" instead of "0,38" as value (it is a german document, so I need another separator). How is this possible?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    nodes near coords]
\addplot coordinates{ (1, 0.381)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Current result]

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [number format in pgfplots axis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31276/number-format-in-pgfplots-axis), which also explains how to change the thousands separator to something other than a comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets **all** decimal numbers to `,` usage.

Thanks to Jake's comment, there is an 'easier' way to get the comma format

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{ngerman} % Is this needed???
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    nodes near coords]
\addplot coordinates{ (1, 0.381)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Older version of the code

`\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}}`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    nodes near coords]
\addplot coordinates{ (1, 0.381)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works - thank you :). Hust as hint, if another find this thread: it is a good idea to include \usepackage{icomma} too (remove space after comma in numbers)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot that indeed. I will update the screen shot

Comment: @SunBlack It is better to use `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set decimal separator={\relax{,}}}` IMHO, since comma has two meanings really and you need to distinguish them. Package `icomma` prevents this somehow.

Comment: You can achieve this without additional packages by using `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}` instead of `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}}`

Comment: @yo': Thanks, I changed the old answer to use `icomma`