# pgfplots - number format, 1234 to 1.2K, 1999 to 2.0K (rounded), 1234567 to 1.2M etc

Tags: pgfplots

How do I format a number just like the title says in pgfplots?

Comment: Related: [number format in pgfplots axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31276/152550).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Most likely this has been done somewhere already but I cannot find it. I copied the units from the `pgfplots` library `units` and made them part of a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand{\FormatNumber}[1]{\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}%
\pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\tmp}{\Mantissa}{\Exponent}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(\Exponent<3 && \Exponent>-3,1,0)}%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1,zerofill}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{\Mantissa}\,%
\ifnum\itest=1%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexp}{\Exponent-2}%
\text{\ifcase\myexp\relax%
c%
\or%1 
d%
\or%-1 
da%
\or%-2 
h%
\fi}%
\else%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexp}{int(9+\Exponent/3)}%
\text{\ifcase\myexp%
\or%24
y%
\or%21
z%
\or%18
a%
\or%15
f%
\or%12
p%
\or%9
n%
\or%6
$\mu$%
\or%3
m%
\or%0
%
\or%-3
k%
\or%-6
M%
\or%-9
G%
\or%-12
T%
\or%-15
P%
\or%-18
E%
\or%-21
Z%
\or%-24
Y%
\fi}%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\verb|\FormatNumber{1234}| \FormatNumber{1234}\par
\verb|\FormatNumber{1999}| \FormatNumber{1999}\par 
\verb|\FormatNumber{1234567}| \FormatNumber{1234567}\par
\verb|\FormatNumber{123}| \FormatNumber{123}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

One could combine this with `siunitx` if needed.

Comment: Siunitx comes close with scientific-notation=engineering, but no cigar.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I fail to see that from the `siunitx` manual.