# Automatically convert a number to use the correct SI unit prefix

Tags: siunitx, number

Say one is talking about numbers `10^6`, `10^7`, `10^8`, `10^9` and so forth one can also write them as `1M`, `10M`, `100M`,`1G`, with their corresponding [SI unit prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes).

Is there a way to convert a number on the form

```
 10000000...
 1E6 
 1E-6
-100000...
```

To a number with  SI unit prefixes automatically?

```
------------------------------------
  Input              |      Output
------------------------------------
 \prefix{1000000}    |         1M
 \prefix{10000000}   |        10M
 \prefix{100000000}  |       100M
 \prefix{1000000000} |         1G
 \prefix{1E6}        |         1M
 \prefix{-1E6}       |         1μ
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what you hope the usage syntax should look like?

Comment: Done. I added an example

Comment: Thanks.  I was just wondering if it has to interact with `siunitx` calls in a prescribed way, or is what you are showing in your example sufficient?

Comment: No interaction needed.

Comment: What about numbers not powers of 10? How should, say 3141.592653, be printed?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik My understanding is that the application is specifically for powers of 10 *only*, though the OP can correct me.

Comment: The whole purpose is to solve the problems for powers of 10 =)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, N3buchadnezzar -- Okay, thanks, just checking :-)

Comment: `pgfplots` has a library called `units` for these things.

Comment: @marmot Maybe you could turn that comment into an answer? =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I already had used it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485228/121799). It is slightly different from your problem because it also does rounding and such things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This allows any (valid, of course) value or expression to be input. The code (ab)uses the LaTeX3 floating point unit to parse the input expression and convert it to exponential notation. With that the code just looks for the correct prefix to apply to that number. Numbers outside the range are printed with more digits to make the number fit the nearest prefix (*i.e.,* `1E28` prints `10000 Y` and `1E-28` prints `0.0001 y`).

The `\prefix` macro (which should probably be called *`\postfix`* :-) is expandable, takes one argument, the number, and prints the it followed by the prefix.

The `\prefixSI` macro is not expandable and has the same signature as `siunitx`'s `\SI` macro. `\prefixSI` evaluates its first mandatory argument with `\prefix` (`\nebu_prefix:n`, actually), as described above, and passes it to `\SI`. The selected prefix is stored in `\prefix` (inside a group, so that the *macro* `\prefix` can be used agian) which can be used in an unit expression, for example `\prefixSI{1000}{\prefix\metre}` prints `1 km`.

Prefixes can be declared with `\setprefix \<siunitx prefix macro> { <prefix> } { <value> }`, like `\setprefix \centi { c } { -2 }`. Make sure that the `\<siunitx prefix macro>` exists. If you're not going to use `\prefixSI` then you can use `\relax` there.

And, as the code uses `expl3`'s floating point unit to parse the number, you are not limited to the `aEb` or decimal notation. You can do any floating point operation implemented in `l3fp` ([look here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#section.22.9) for a list of them), like `a*10^b` or any other.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Internals
\int_new:N \l__nebu_min_prefix_int
\tl_new:N \l__nebu_base_number_tl
\tl_new:N \l__nebu_mode_tl
\cs_new:Npn \nebu_prefix:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \__nebu_prefix:n
      { \exp_args:Nf \fp_to_scientific:n { \tl_lower_case:n {#1} } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__nebu_prefix:n #1
  { \__nebu_prefix:nwnw #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__nebu_prefix:nwnw #1 e #2 \q_stop
  { \__nebu_find_prefix:nnn {#2} {#1} {1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__nebu_find_prefix:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \tl_if_exist:cT { l__nebu_ #1 \tl_use:N \l__nebu_mode_tl _prefix_tl }
      {
        \use_i_delimit_by_q_stop:nw
          { \__nebu_output:nnn {#2} {#1} {#3} }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT {#1} < \l__nebu_min_prefix_int
      {
        \use_i_delimit_by_q_stop:nw
          {
            \exp_args:Nf \__nebu_find_prefix:nnn
              { \int_eval:n { \l__nebu_min_prefix_int } } {#2}
              { #3 / 1\prg_replicate:nn { \l__nebu_min_prefix_int - #1 }{ 0 } }
          }
      }
    \use_i:nn
      {
        \exp_args:Nf \__nebu_find_prefix:nnn
          { \int_eval:n {#1-1} } {#2} {#3*10}
      }
      \q_stop
  }
\exp_args_generate:n { fv }
\cs_new:Npn \__nebu_output:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \exp_args:Nfv \nebu_output:nn
      { \fp_to_decimal:n {#1*#3} } { l__nebu_ #2 \tl_use:N \l__nebu_mode_tl _prefix_tl }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nebu_prefix_set:Nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \exp_args:Nxx \__nebu_prefix_set:nnN
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#2} } { \int_eval:n {#3} } #1
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nebu_prefix_set:nnN #1 #2 #3
  {
    \tl_clear_new:c { l__nebu_ #2 _prefix_tl }
    \tl_clear_new:c { l__nebu_ #2 _siunitx_prefix_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l__nebu_ #2 _prefix_tl } {#1}
    \tl_set:cn { l__nebu_ #2 _siunitx_prefix_tl } {#3}
    \int_set:Nn \l__nebu_min_prefix_int { \int_min:nn {#2} { \l__nebu_min_prefix_int } }
  }
% User interface
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \prefix { m }
  { \nebu_prefix:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \nebu_output:nn #1 #2 { #1\, \textrm{#2} }
\NewDocumentCommand \setprefix { m m m }
  { \nebu_prefix_set:Nnn #1 {#2} {#3} }
\DeclareSIPrefix \none { } { 0 }
\setprefix \none { } { 0 }
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nebu_store:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_base_number_tl {#1}
    \cs_set:Npn \prefix {#2}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \prefixSI { o m o m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \cs_set_eq:NN \nebu_output:nn \__nebu_store:nn
      \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_mode_tl { _siunitx }
      \nebu_prefix:n {#2}
      \SI [#1] { \l__nebu_base_number_tl } [#3] {#4}
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setprefix \yocto { y } { -24 }
\setprefix \zepto { z } { -21 }
\setprefix \atto  { a } { -18 }
\setprefix \femto { f } { -15 }
\setprefix \pico  { p } { -12 }
\setprefix \nano  { n } { -9 }
\setprefix \micro { \SIUnitSymbolMicro } { -6 }
\setprefix \milli { m } { -3 }
\setprefix \centi { c } { -2 }
\setprefix \deci  { d } { -1 }
\setprefix \deca  { da } { 1 }
\setprefix \hecto { h }  { 2 }
\setprefix \kilo  { k }  { 3 }
\setprefix \mega  { M }  { 6 }
\setprefix \giga  { G }  { 9 }
\setprefix \tera  { T }  { 12 }
\setprefix \peta  { P }  { 15 }
\setprefix \exa   { E }  { 18 }
\setprefix \zetta { Z }  { 21 }
\setprefix \yotta { Y }  { 24 }

\begin{document}
\prefix{1}\par
\prefix{4E6}\par
\prefix{1E-15}\par
\prefix{1e-6}\par
\prefix{300}\par
\prefix{1000000}\par
\prefix{.001}\par
\prefix{.000004}\par
\prefix{1E5}\par
\prefix{10000}\par
\prefix{.0001}\par
\prefix{5E7}\par
\prefix{1E-5}\par
\prefix{3E8}\par
\prefix{1E-4}\par
\prefix{1E-24}\par
\prefix{1E-28}\par
\prefix{1E24}\par
\prefix{1E28}\par
\prefix{1e3*pi}\par
\prefixSI{1e3*pi}{\prefix\metre}\par
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: How would `10E-4 metres` look? ;-) Great answer!

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Thanks! A millimetre: `1 mm`? Is there something wrong?

Comment: Well in most countries 10^-4 metres is known as 0.1 mm, but I understand why it displays it as 1 mm. Just something to be aware of when using this answer

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar `10e-4 m` is `10×10^-4 m`, which is `10×0.1mm`, which is `1mm`. The `e` in `10e-4` is short for `×10^`, so the leading 10 multiplies the whole thing, thus the difference you see.

Answer (score 4):

EDITED to solve both input forms.  EDITED so that either capital or lowercase E is permitted in the scientific notation (e.g., `1E6` or `1e6`).

EDITED to automatically discern multipliers of 1, 10 or 100 on standard units.

If the prefix is outside the range of 1E-24 to 1E26, a `??` is output.

See **SUPPLEMENT** for more general use of multipliers (outside of 1, 10, 100).

As this answer has expanded with EDITS, let me explan the logic.  There are 3 macros that call each other in sequence.  Let me work my way from the end to the beginning.  The lowest level macro is

```
\prefixSN[<multiplier>]{1E<SI-prefix-integer>}
```

The multiplier defaults to 1, but can be 10 or 100.  The SI-prefix-integer are specific integers for which an SI prefix is defined (-24, -21, ...-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, ...21, 24).  If the provided integer is not in this list, a `??` is output.  If the integer is in the list, the appropriate SI-prefix is output following the multiplier.

The macro that feeds `\prefixSN` in the proper syntax is called `\prefixmult`, with syntax

```
\prefixmult{1E<integer>}
```

Here integer should be in the range -24 to 26.  Based on the value of the integer, it sets the prefix as 1, 10, or 100, and adjusts the integer to the next lower SI standard value.  For example if the input to `\prefixmult` was `1E5`, it would set the call `\prefixSI[100]{1E3}`.

The top-level macro, `\prefix`, which feeds `\prefixmult` its integer format, can take input in four possible form s:

```
\prefix{1E<integer>}
\prefix{1e<integer>}
\prefix{10<...>0}
\prefix{.0<...>01}
```

It sorts through looking for an `E` or `e`.  Finding one, it passes the capital-E form to `\prefixmult` with the associated integer.  If no `E` is found, it looks for a decimal point, a `1` and multiple `0` tokens.  Based on what it finds, it reconstructs the associated integer based on the number of zeros and passes it onto `\prefixmult`.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,listofitems}
\newcommand\prefixSN[2][1]{#1\,\prefixSNaux#2\relax}
\def\prefixSNaux 1E#1\relax{%
  \ifnum#1=0\relax\else
  \ifnum#1=-1\relax\textrm{d}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-2\relax\textrm{c}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-3\relax\textrm{m}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-6\relax\textrm{\ensuremath{\mu}}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-9\relax\textrm{n}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-12\relax\textrm{p}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-15\relax\textrm{f}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-18\relax\textrm{a}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-21\relax\textrm{z}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-24\relax\textrm{y}\else  
  \ifnum#1=1\relax\textrm{da}\else  
  \ifnum#1=2\relax\textrm{h}\else  
  \ifnum#1=3\relax\textrm{k}\else  
  \ifnum#1=6\relax\textrm{M}\else  
  \ifnum#1=9\relax\textrm{G}\else  
  \ifnum#1=12\relax\textrm{T}\else  
  \ifnum#1=15\relax\textrm{P}\else  
  \ifnum#1=18\relax\textrm{E}\else  
  \ifnum#1=21\relax\textrm{Z}\else  
  \ifnum#1=24\relax\textrm{Y}\else 
  ??%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand\prefix[1]{%
  \setsepchar{1E||1e}%
  \readlist\scinot{#1}%
  \ifnum\scinotlen>1\relax
    \itemtomacro\scinot[2]\temp%
    \expandafter\prefixmult\expandafter{\expandafter1\expandafter E\temp}%
  \else
    \setsepchar{./1/0}%
    \readlist\zerocount{#1}%
    \ifnum\zerocountlen=1\relax
      \expandafter\prefixmult\expandafter{\expandafter1\expandafter E%
        \the\numexpr\listlen\zerocount[1,2]-1\relax}%
    \else
      \expandafter\prefixmult\expandafter{\expandafter1\expandafter E%
        \expandafter-\the\numexpr\listlen\zerocount[2,1]\relax}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand\prefixmult[1]{\prefixmultaux#1\relax}
\def\prefixmultaux 1E#1\relax{%
  \setsepchar{E4||E7||E10||E13||E16||E19||E22||E25||%
              E-5||E-8||E-11||E-14||E-17||E-20||E-23}%
  \readlist\factormult{E#1}%
  \ifnum\factormultlen>1\relax
    \prefixSN[10]{1E\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}
  \else
    \setsepchar{E5||E8||E11||E14||E17||E20||E23||E26||%
                E-4||E-7||E-10||E-13||E-16||E-19||E-22}%
    \readlist\factormult{E#1}%
    \ifnum\factormultlen>1\relax
      \prefixSN[100]{1E\the\numexpr#1-2\relax}
    \else
      \prefixSN[1]{1E#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\prefix{1E6}\par
\prefix{1E-15}\par
\prefix{1e-6}\par
\prefix{100}\par
\prefix{1000000}\par
\prefix{.001}\par
\prefix{.000001}\par
\prefix{1E5}\par
\prefix{10000}\par
\prefix{.0001}\par
\prefix{1E7}\par
\prefix{1E-5}\par
\prefix{1E8}\par
\prefix{1E-4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Not sure if this is an improvement, as it seems to me that the `\prefix` should deal solely in powers of 10.  However, if one wished for a more general implementation that could handle any multiplier **of a single significant digit**, then here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,listofitems}
\newcommand\prefixSN[2][1]{#1\,\prefixSNaux#2\relax}
\def\prefixSNaux 1E#1\relax{%
  \ifnum#1=0\relax\else
  \ifnum#1=-1\relax\textrm{d}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-2\relax\textrm{c}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-3\relax\textrm{m}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-6\relax\textrm{\ensuremath{\mu}}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-9\relax\textrm{n}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-12\relax\textrm{p}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-15\relax\textrm{f}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-18\relax\textrm{a}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-21\relax\textrm{z}\else  
  \ifnum#1=-24\relax\textrm{y}\else  
  \ifnum#1=1\relax\textrm{da}\else  
  \ifnum#1=2\relax\textrm{h}\else  
  \ifnum#1=3\relax\textrm{k}\else  
  \ifnum#1=6\relax\textrm{M}\else  
  \ifnum#1=9\relax\textrm{G}\else  
  \ifnum#1=12\relax\textrm{T}\else  
  \ifnum#1=15\relax\textrm{P}\else  
  \ifnum#1=18\relax\textrm{E}\else  
  \ifnum#1=21\relax\textrm{Z}\else  
  \ifnum#1=24\relax\textrm{Y}\else 
  ??%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand\prefix[1]{%
  \setsepchar{E||e}%
  \readlist\scinot{#1}%
  \ifnum\scinotlen>1\relax
    \itemtomacro\scinot[1]\premult%
    \itemtomacro\scinot[2]\temp%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\prefixmult
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\premult\expandafter E\temp}%
  \else
    \setsepchar{./1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9/0}%
    \readlist\zerocount{#1}%
    \ifnum\zerocountlen=1\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\zerocountsep[1,1]}%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\prefixmult
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\temp\expandafter E%
        \the\numexpr\listlen\zerocount[1,2]-1\relax}%
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\zerocountsep[2,1]}%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\prefixmult
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\temp\expandafter E%
        \expandafter-\the\numexpr\listlen\zerocount[2,1]\relax}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand\prefixmult[1]{\prefixmultaux#1\relax}
\def\prefixmultaux #1E#2\relax{%
  \setsepchar{E4||E7||E10||E13||E16||E19||E22||E25||%
              E-5||E-8||E-11||E-14||E-17||E-20||E-23}%
  \readlist\factormult{E#2}%
  \ifnum\factormultlen>1\relax
    \prefixSN[#10]{1E\the\numexpr#2-1\relax}
  \else
    \setsepchar{E5||E8||E11||E14||E17||E20||E23||E26||%
                E-4||E-7||E-10||E-13||E-16||E-19||E-22}%
    \readlist\factormult{E#2}%
    \ifnum\factormultlen>1\relax
      \prefixSN[#100]{1E\the\numexpr#2-2\relax}
    \else
      \prefixSN[#1]{1E#2}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\prefix{4E6}\par
\prefix{1E-15}\par
\prefix{1e-6}\par
\prefix{300}\par
\prefix{1000000}\par
\prefix{.001}\par
\prefix{.000004}\par
\prefix{1E5}\par
\prefix{10000}\par
\prefix{.0001}\par
\prefix{5E7}\par
\prefix{1E-5}\par
\prefix{3E8}\par
\prefix{1E-4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Now all that remains is for someone to figure out how to convert `\prefix{10000}` to `10k` =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Ask and ye shall receive.  Done.

Answer (score 4):

This supports both exponential and standard notation.

No check about the nonzero digit is performed, the input is assumed to be of the form

```
1<sequence of zeros>
-1<sequence of zeros>
1e<exponent>
1E<exponent>
-1e<exponent>
-1E<exponent>
```

The range is `-1E-26` to `1E26`. Numbers outside this range silently fail. You can add control about the range.

Here's the code: note that the bulk of the work is performed by `\__nebuch_prefix_exp:nn` (precisely by the `:ee` variant).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % also loads xparse and expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\prefix}{m}
 {
  \nebuch_prefix:e { \tl_lower_case:n { #1 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebuch_prefix:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq { e } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq > 1 }
   {% there was e/E
    \__nebuch_prefix_exp:ee
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq { 1 } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq { 2 } }
   }
   {% no e/E
    \__nebuch_prefix_long:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebuch_prefix:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nebuch_prefix_exp:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #2 } { 3 } < 0 }
   {
    \__nebuch_prefix_exp:ee
     { #1 \prg_replicate:nn { 3 + \int_mod:nn { #2 } { 3 } } { 0 } }
     { \int_eval:n { #2 - 3 - \int_mod:nn { #2 } { 3 } } }
   }
   {
    \SI
     {
      #1 % 1 or -1
      \prg_replicate:nn { \int_mod:nn { #2 } { 3 } } { 0 }
     }
     {
      \int_case:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { #2 } { 3 } }
       {
        {-8}{\yocto\voidunit}
        {-7}{\zepto\voidunit}
        {-6}{\atto\voidunit}
        {-5}{\femto\voidunit}
        {-4}{\pico\voidunit}
        {-3}{\nano\voidunit}
        {-2}{\micro\voidunit}
        {-1}{\milli\voidunit}
        {0}{\!\voidunit}
        {1}{\kilo\voidunit}
        {2}{\mega\voidunit}
        {3}{\giga\voidunit}
        {4}{\tera\voidunit}
        {5}{\peta\voidunit}
        {6}{\exa\voidunit}
        {7}{\zetta\voidunit}
        {8}{\yotta\voidunit}
       }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebuch_prefix_exp:nn {ee}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nebuch_prefix_long:n
 {
  % count the number of zeros
  \regex_split:nnN { (\-*1+) } { #1 } \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq
  \__nebuch_prefix_exp:ee
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq { 2 } }
   { \tl_count:e { \seq_item:Nn \l__nebuch_prefix_input_seq { 3 } } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count:n { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareSIUnit{\voidunit}{\relax}

\begin{document}

\prefix{1e0}

\prefix{1e2}

\prefix{1E4}

\prefix{-1E20}

\prefix{1}

\prefix{10}

\prefix{100}

\prefix{1000}

\prefix{10000}

\prefix{100000}

\prefix{1000000}

\prefix{10000000}

\prefix{100000000}

\prefix{1000000000}

\prefix{-10000000000}

\prefix{100000000000}

\prefix{1E6}

\prefix{1E24}

\prefix{-1E-6}

\prefix{1E-8}

\prefix{-1E-7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With new version of siunitx, it is now possible to do:

```
    \DeclareSIUnit\noop{\relax}

    \qty[drop-zero-decimal
         round-precision = 3, 
         scientific-notation = engineering,
         exponent-to-prefix
        ]{1000000}{\noop}
```