Can siunitx condense 1230000 to "1.23M", etc.?
Is there an option for the "siunitx" package that automatically condenses numbers using SI prefixes as shorthand -- e.g., input "1230000" but output "1.23M"?
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[]{1230000} % goal: "1.23M"
\num[]{45600} % goal: "45.6k"
\end{document}


see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497228/automatically-convert-a-number-to-use-the-correct-si-unit-prefix
